# WindowsでインストールしたGUIアプリの繰り返し処理を自動で操作できる方法ってないでしょうか？

Tags: python, windows, matlab

現在、GUIベースのANSYSと呼ばれるシミュレーションソフトや、計測したデータを画像処理する市販のソフトを手動で操作しているのですが、例えば

1. あるパラメータを0〜100まで1刻みで実行させる。
2. 得られた画像を出力して保存する。

という作業が煩雑で自動化したいなと考えています。この様な手動操作は、数が増えてくると非常に煩雑なのですが、コードベースで自動化させるライブラリなどは無いのでしょうか？

現在、主にOSはWindows10, 言語はMatlabやPythonを用いているので、できればこの環境で(この環境で無くとも)自動化する方法が無いかご存知の方居ましたらご教示頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: 名前からすると [ANSYSトップ > 製品紹介](https://www.cybernet.co.jp/ansys/product/) でしょうか。問い合わせれば事例等と共に教えてくれるのでは？ [プロジェクト画面の処理を自動化したり、複数の解析システムを一括処理したい。](https://www.cybernet.co.jp/ansys/product/custom/custom05.html), [UIDLを用いたANSYS GUIのカスタマイズ](https://www.cybernet.co.jp/ansys/case/tips/14.html)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ANSYSではVBAやPythonが使える事は知っていたのですが、情報が少なく他に良い方法が無いかと思い質問させて頂きました。やはりご回答者様のご指摘通り、Pythonでマクロを組むのが正統な方法みたいですね。

Comment: 流行りのRPAツールも考えられなくはないですが、どうしても間接的になるので、使用しているソフトウェア自身にカスタマイズの機能が用意されているなら、そちらを使う方が確実で早いでしょう。

Comment: 自分としても、RPAツール的な物で上手く自動化する方法があると良いなと考えておりました。ご指摘の通り、カスタマイズの機能が提供されているVBAかPythonでどこまで出来るか検証してみたいと思います。アドバイスどうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score -3):

[こういうこ](http://d.sunnyone.org/2014/09/windowsuiui-automation-powershell.html)とですか？
検査キーワード：windows ui 自動化